# Can't register google endpoint entity - android

Tags: android, entity, endpoint

I'm using `ObjectifyService.register(Chat.class);` in order to try to register the following Class as an entity, but after I'm rebuilding my project, I get an error if I try to create a new `Chat` entity and I can't find the class in the `generated-source` folder:

```
package com.miraiweb.backend.model;

import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity;
import com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

@Entity
public class Chat {
    @Id @Getter @Setter String id;
    @Getter @Setter List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public static Chat createChat(){
        Chat chat = new Chat();
        chat.setId("" + ofy().factory().allocateId(Chat.class).getId());
        return chat;
    }
}
```